# How to render an <image> in a background WPF process?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm taking Silverlight XAML and sending it to a web service that renders the XAML in a STA thread and generates a PNG image. All the XAML renders correctly except the `<image>` entries which 'appear' to load correctly when their `Source` property is set in WPF but the PNG does not show the referenced image - what am I doing wrong ?

The core of the code that I am using is as below. The `value` object is a DTO from Silverlight that contains the XAML in the string that ends up as the `sXAML` local property and the Image URI is in the `value.ImageURL` property.

```
  var canvas = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(sXAML)));

  var obj = canvas.FindName("BGImage");
  Image img = null;
  if (obj != null)
  {
    img = obj as Image;
    img.ImageFailed += img_ImageFailed;
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ImageURL, UriKind.Absolute));
  }

  canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(463d, 381d)));
  canvas.UpdateLayout();

  var mem = new MemoryStream();
  var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(463, 381, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
  bmp.Render(canvas);

  var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
  encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
  encoder.Save(mem);

  FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\out.png", FileMode.Create);
  mem.WriteTo(fs);
  fs.Close();
```

NB: The `img_ImageFailed` event handler is never invoked indicating that the `img` Source assignment was successful in some way.

Comment: Still unable to get WPF to render the background image - not to worry. I loaded the background image into a Bitmap and modified it with the rendered XAML bitmap image and successfully generated the desired image.

Answer (score 2):

Things I would try:

1) In your WPF app, if you 'render' your dynamically loaded `Canvas` to display in a Window, does it all work (images included)?

2) Have you tried attaching a `Loaded` handler to the `img` object to see *when* the image is actually loaded?

3) Assuming #1 works - where are the images located (are they on the internet/local web server)? If you put a breakpoint in the code on

```
bmp.Render(canvas);
```

and wait a while before stepping on - does the image *then* appear in the rendered output?

I suspect the image is being 'downloaded' asynchronously and you are rendering the `Canvas` too early, before the `Image` object has resolved its source.

**[UPDATE 29-Jan-09]**
**possible solution**

I copied you code down exactly and gave it a try. When I used a 'local' image location (eg. "c:\images\splash.jpg") the image was rendered fine in the output jpeg. When I used a URL (eg. "http://localhost/images/splash.jpg") it did NOT appear (as you describe).

So I modified your code as follows (to try and FORCE the image to be downloaded - will only work for http: image references) --

```
if (obj != null)
{
    img = obj as Image;
    // new stuff
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = getCachedURLStream(new Uri(ImageURL));
    bi.EndInit();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.Source = bi;
    img.EndInit();
    //img.ImageFailed += img_ImageFailed;
    //img.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(img_Loaded);
    //img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImageURL, UriKind.Absolute));
}
public static Stream getCachedURLStream(Uri url)
{
    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response;
    webrequest.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Default);
    response = webrequest.GetResponse();
    Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
    BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(s, 8192);
    return bs;
}
```

(the `getCachedURLStream` method is from [synchronous image loading](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e76d4534-8f92-44be-a3d7-8bfa2ca9600d/) - it's kinda extraneous but I just wanted a quick chunk of code to test) and it seemed to then work (image visible in JPEG). Maybe that will work in your scenario?

Comment: If you don't cast the return of WebRequest.Create(url) to a HttpWebRequest it will work for local addresses ("file://c:/foo.png") or apparently new Uri("@"C:\temp\foo.png").  Also of note: the webrequest.CachePolicy line is required, at least in the context I need this fix.